# Permanent magnets near wifi device

Tags: wireless, wifi, magnetics, interference

### Background

I have a small circuit that consists of a microcontroller operating on 14Mhz and a wifi module. This circuit is enclosed in a small plastic box. I am considering gluing a few magnets on this box in order to install it on a metal surface, and I was wondering how bad it could influence the circuit and the wifi connection, since these magnets will be placed really close to the circuitry.
Here are some technical details:

- Magnets are Neodymium Disc 1/4" X 1/16" N32 grade.
- [Plastic Box](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Widgets/SFE_Box.pdf) is 4.22" X 3.75" X 1.21"
- Wifi module is [RN-XV](http://dlnmh9ip6v2uc.cloudfront.net/datasheets/Wireless/WiFi/WiFly-RN-XV-DS.pdf) (802.11 b/g, 2402 ~ 2480MHz, TX 0dBm to +12dBm, RX -83dBm)

### I would like to know:

- Should I expect bad interferences?
- Are there any special considerations where to glue the magnets on the box, except from "away from the wifi module" ?

Comment: Why not conduct a test? Tape the magnets on, and do a speed test and check the signal status. Then take off the magnets and try again. Also have you considered velcro instead?

Comment: @Passerby I will perform some tests when I get the magnets. Velcro is less favorable since it forces me to install it always in the same spot.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should not expect any problems, other than the same problem any piece of metal poses.

The magnetic field does not mask or influence any GHz transmissions.  TV, Radio, 60Hz power lines should not pose a problem either.  Think of the magnet as 0Hz; a DC electromagnetic field that is stuck in the magnetic form, with zero electrical component.

Comment: Finally had some time to check this. As you said, the magnets don't affect the circuit.

Comment: Coming back to this... I suppose that inductors and transformers could see diminished performance due to the material being saturated, if the field was strong enough.  Temperature has a similar effect on most materials.